# How to evaluate an Indefinite Integral of this sort?

Tags: integration

May I seek assistance on how this integral can be evaluated?

$\int_{\Sigma} \frac{dydz}{[a_{o}(y^{2}+z^{2})+2f_{o}y+2g_{o}z+c_{o}]^{2}}$ where $a_{o}c_{o}-f_{o}^{2}-g_{0}^{2}=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ a rectangular region?

Comment: Yes of course. I'm asking if we may assume that region is rectangular.

Comment: @DavidH, yes, the region is rectangular.

Comment: Also, I just noticed the $y^z$ term in the denominator. Are you sure this isn't perhaps a typo, and should be $y^2$?

Comment: @DavidH, thanks for pointing this out. Yes, it is indeed a typo. I had corrected my initial post.

Comment: @DavidH, how do you think of this integral? Do you think it can be evaluated?

Comment: I do think it can be evaluated explicitly in terms of elementary functions, but expect the final result to be a VERY ugly eight-variable expression.

Comment: @DavidH, can you show me a bit how can I evaluate this? I am very interested in this. I will upvote your answer and will try to continue myself the remaining of the calculation.

Comment: It so happens that your integral can be rewritten (using a linear change of variables) in the following form: $\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}t\int_{c}^{d}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{4}{\left(t^{2}+u^{2}+1\right)^{2}}$. This is still a messy integral to compute, but both the inner and outer integrations are doable with elementary calculus. Wolfram Alpha was even able to find both antiderivatives without timing-out!